# Follow a path with tween.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tweenjs

I'am building a board for a game, it's a trival pursuit like , and I'm in a dead end, after than the player throw the dice and he chose a case, his pions have to
move forward , for exemple he is in the case 1 ,had a 4 after throwing the dice chose the case 3 and move.
Here is my problem ,using my example , when the player chose the case 3 the pions have to go to the case 2 and finaly 3 , but with this code my pions go directly to the cases 3 and to be honest I don't why ,
here is my code :

```
 attachEvent(_this, index,a,s) {
 let b =a-2

 _this.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(this.pions.position)

 if(index>=a){

_this.domEvents.addEventListener(_this.cases[index],                                                      'click',function(event) {
for ( var i = a-1; i <= index; i++) {
  _this.stepByStep(_this.tween,_this.cases[i].position)

}

  for (var i = a; i < a + s; i++) {
    try {
   _this.mat[i].color.setHex(0xFFD700)
    _this.domEvents.removeEventListener(_this.cases[i], 'click', false)

      }
    catch(err) {
console.log(err.message)
      }
    try {
    _this.mat[b].color.setHex(0xFFD700)
    _this.domEvents.removeEventListener(_this.cases[b], 'click', false)
     }
    catch(err) {
         console.log(err.message)
       }
        b--;
}




  }, false)

  }else{

  _this.domEvents.addEventListener(_this.cases[index], 'click',     function(event) {
for ( var i = a-1; i >=index; i--) {
  _this.stepByStep(this,i)

}

 for (var i = a; i < a + s; i++) {
    try {
   _this.mat[i].color.setHex(0xFFD700)
   _this.domEvents.removeEventListener(_this.cases[i], 'click', false)

      }
    catch(err) {
          console.log(err.message)
      }
       try {
     _this.mat[b].color.setHex(0xFFD700)
     _this.domEvents.removeEventListener(_this.cases[b], 'click', false)

     }
    catch(err) {
          console.log(err.message)
      }

   b--;
}

},false)

  }

 }

stepByStep(tween,position)
{

        tween.to({
        x: position.x,
        y: position.y,
        z: 5},1000)
        .start();


   }
```

this is the function that I call when the player click on a case 
index : the objectif (3 in my exemple )
a : the position of the poins
s : the value of the dice

Comment: Is there any chance that you could provide a live code example?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kasper09/pen/MqoaGG